# Mark Overridden member as obsolete

Tags: vb.net

I have a class structure like this:

```
Public class Student
    Public Overridable Function SayHello() As String
    End Function
End Class

Public Class Undergraduate
    Inherits Student

    <Obsolete("Marked as obselete on 04/11/14.", True)> _
    Public Overrides Function SayHello() As String
    End Function
End Class
```

If an instance of `Undergraduate` calls `SayHello`, then I want it to call the `Student` version of the method.  I thought that applying the `ObseleteAttribute` would achieve this, however it does not.  Do I have to comment out or delete the overriding `Undergraduate.SayHello` method?

Comment: that is not how Attributes work - the Type or method has no knowledge of the Attributes which decorate it.  declare `Student.SayHello` as `NotOverridable` if you truly want it, and only it, to be used.  Or modify all the derived classes to: `mybase.SayHello`

Comment: You are not overriding it rather hiding it in your derived class.

Comment: @Plutonix, the answer is to use MyBase.

Comment: `I want it to call the Student version`: then yes, comment out the entire function in Undergraduate.  Should have been easy for you to try it.

Comment: actually, `MyBase.SayHello` is kind of a quick way to route the call back to the base class; using `Obsolete` warns developers (via VS's squiggly line) that they should not be using it (anymore); while `NotOverridable` puts the hammer down and requires all inherited types to stop using the overrides right this second.  it depends on the extent and degree of resolution you wish to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ObsoleteAttribute` does not cause the compiler to ignore the presence of the method.  The compiler still compiles the method into the assembly, so if it is called successfully, the `Undergraduate` version of it will still be called.  The attribute is simply metadata that the compiler embeds in the assembly to describe the method.  The attribute will, ideally speaking, stop consumers from calling the method, but it does not stop the method from existing.  In order to force it to use the base `Student` version of the method, you can either make it a pass-through method that calls the base method, like this:

```
Public Class Undergraduate
    Inherits Student

    Public Overrides Function SayHello() As String
        MyBase.SayHello()
    End Function
End Class
```

Or, more simply, just remove the method entirely:

```
Public Class Undergraduate
    Inherits Student

    'No longer necessary, use base implementation
    'Public Overrides Function SayHello() As String
    'End Function
End Class
```